# CKEditor: POST is not receiving large string over 3355 chars (max_input_vars)

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

New info: At the present moment the best way out is settings a limit to how many chars text area can have.

I haven't tried but i think that a better option would have been if I was to have a template saved in the database. In the template I would have predefined areas (similar to widgets) in which data would go. At the text area I display template with those predefined areas with default data, user amends areas that are currently set with their own data and on submit PHP receives something like $_POST = array('area1' => 'some data', 'area2' => 'some data'...);. Set a limit of chars for each to be something between 1000 and 3000.

---

I have a standard textarea

```
<textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
```

$message - contains an HTML template that user would than modify in the textarea

When I submit the form in PHP script i catch $_POST and print the values

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

For some reason $_POST['message'] returns '["message"]=> string(0) ""'

Could be related to the POST size, but i am not so sure about it because I have 8M and it should be more than enough. I have also noticed that $_POST breaks when I have 38 chars in Title (which is one of the variables that is stored in POST) and message is more than 3355 in length.

I have also looked up a PHP.ini variabl "max_input_vars", in my PHP.ini I dont have it set.

My form code:

```
<form action="" class="" method="post" id="add_newsletter">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="control-label">Message<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="message" class="ckeditor form-control message" id="message"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn green">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'message' );
</script>
```

If I replace the text in the message textarea after load form returns correct POST value.

The HTML message that is stored in the $message variable is 5854 chars and is wrapped by :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<body>
<div style="max-width: 800px; margin: 0; padding: 30px 0;">
    <img src="../img/email-header.png" /><br/><br />
    Some text is here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the text how exactly you got the message from $_POST and how you passed it from the form to begin with.

Comment: put your form code also

Comment: Please put the rest of your code. :)

Comment: where is the submit button ? where is the action of form Specify

Comment: ive updated html and the code that is stored in the $message variable. I couldn't put full $message because of it's size.

Comment: I have also added an extra finding that shows that $_POST['message'] that stores a message broke due to the length of the message. If message is bellow 3356 than $_POST works fine.

Comment: make sure to update the textarea element before sending data. Anything inside CKEditor container is in another iframe